# How to get log in when having multiple email

Tags: laravel, laravel-4.2

Having same email id but password different

```
abc@xyz.com => 123456
abc@xyz.com =>  987654
```

I want to get logged in after match email and password

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials, true)) {
    //Check first email and password if it does match return true else false
}
```

How could this possible to achieve, please guide and elobrate if possible thanks a ton in advance

Comment: email should be unique, not ? What is the logic behind this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by retrieving all Users with the given email.

```
$users = User::where('email', $request->get('email'))->get();

$users->each(function (User $user) {
    if (\Hash::check($request->get('password'), $user->password)) {
        Auth::login($user);
    }
});
```

You then iterate over all the users and check the  password yourself.

Comment: `Hash::make` would not work , rather use `Hash::check()`

Comment: Auth::login does not seems to work anything we need to install for this..?

Comment: @Sachin it depends what laravel version you are using. [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#other-authentication-methods) is the documentation for the current version.

Comment: @Sachin _"The given object must be an implementation of the  Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable contract."_ This sentence is the most relevant.

Comment: I'm having 4.2 laravel installed please guide

Comment: @Sachin it is the same for Laravel 4.2. See [this documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#manually).

Comment: I read we are fine here but is there any issue with above code

Because when i do

Comment: foreach($users as $user){ 
     //fetch all users with that email
     if (\Hash::check(Input::get('password'), $user->password)) {
            dd($user); // Does work
        }
    }

Comment: @Sachin does your User model implement lluminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable contract? You may want to open a new question for this problem.

Comment: I think you just provide me satisfy answer thank you so much for your time